# Al momento de agregar un nuevo registro este no debe chocar con algún otro horario anteriormente establecido

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

hola soy nuevo en base de datos y me dejaron este ejercicio y la verdad no se como hacerle ya le intente de mil formas y no he podido, me lo pidieron el un proceso almacenado si alguien me podria ayudar, gracias

este tiene un horario de entrada y uno de salida, es de un cine

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `cine`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `horarios`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `horarios`(
    IN Id INT,
    IN SalaId INT,
    IN PeliculaId INT,
    IN HoraInicial TIME,
    IN HoraFinal TIME
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `cine`.`horarios` (`Id`,`SalaId`,`PeliculaId`,`HoraInicial`,`HoraFinal`) 
        VALUES (Id,SalaId,PeliculaId,HoraInicial,HoraFinal)
            where  time_to_sec(horarios.HoraInicial) BETWEEN
                time_to_sec(horarios.HoraFinal)) limit 1;;
     
    
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @BetaM ya lo puse

Comment: José. Si esto es MySQL, entonces, por qué está el tag de SQLServer?

Comment: @Arriel ya lo quite

Comment: @BetaM todavía no me han enseñado eso, solo los procesos, funciones y eventos

Comment: @BetaM si me podras a ayudar a hacer el trigger para darme una idea como

Answer (score 0):

utiliza IF para comparar ademas trata de poner el prefijo a los procedimientos por buenas practicas, espero y te sirva el siguiente ejemplo:

```
USE cine;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_horarios;
DELIMITER $$


CREATE PROCEDURE sp_horarios(
    IN Id_ INT,
    IN SalaId_ INT,
    IN PeliculaId_ INT,
    IN HoraInicial_ TIME,
    IN HoraFinal_ TIME
    )
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM cine.horarios WHERE HoraInicial >= HoraInicial_ AND HoraFinal <= HoraFinal_ ) < 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO cine.horarios (Id,SalaId,PeliculaId,HoraInicial,HoraFinal) VALUES (Id,SalaId,PeliculaId,HoraInicial,HoraFinal);
    END IF;
END$$
```